# Telnet Server not starting

Tags: server, telnet

I am installing Ubuntu Server 13.10 and cant get telnet working on the server. I have installed both xinet.d & telnetd thru apt-get and restarted xinetd but nothing is started when I do a `netstat -l`.
In googling, the trouble I see mention of adding `telnet stream tcp wait telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd /usr/sbin/in.telnetd` line to `/etc/inetd.conf`. I have no `inetd.conf`. I see that inetd has been depracated and I put the line in `xinetd.conf` and restarted xinetd service but still no telnet listening. Can someone advise me on what the proper settings for the telnet server and what files they should be in. Here is the content of my `xinetd.conf` file:

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

defaults
{

# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info

}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d

#:STANDARD: These are standard services.
telnet      stream  tcp nowait  telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

Thanks

Comment: It is 2014, **why** do you want to install telnet?

Comment: Why are you using telnet?  It is an obsolete and insecure protocol.  Use `ssh` instead: it's secure, faster ( uses compression ) and has other nifty features, like the ability to forward ports.

Comment: I'm only using it internally for a computer class and want to kiss.

Comment: Could be a lot of things... probably no one tested it in the last... well... ten years? ;-)

Comment: You seem to think that `/etc/inetd.conf` and `xinetd.conf` use the same format. Have you read `man xinetd`, `man -k xinetd`, `man inetd`, `man -k inetd`, `man telnetd`? Does `/etc/default/telnetd` exist? Have you done `grep telnet /var/log/*`?

Comment: the only reason to use Telnet in 2015 is maybe to debug a network connection in the raw, or as an embedded developer. Otherwise, you should use SSH, especially if you want to keep things simple as you said.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

After installing telnetd and xinetd with command

`sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd`

Create file `telnet` and put in `/etc/xinetd.d`

`sudo nano /etc/xinetd.d/telnet`

```
# default: on
# description: The telnet server serves telnet sessions; it uses
# unencrypted username/password pairs for authentication.
service telnet
{
disable = no
flags = REUSE
socket_type = stream
wait = no
user = root
server = /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
log_on_failure += USERID
}
```

Restart xinetd service

`sudo service xinetd restart`

In `xinetd.conf` you have `includedir /etc/xinetd.d` and don't need line

`telnet      stream  tcp nowait  telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.telnetd`

erase it.

In telnet file you can add more option like:

```
only_from = 192.168.120.0/24 #Only users in 192.168.120.0 can access to
only_from = .bob.com #allow access from bob.com
no_access = 192.168.120.{101,105} #not allow access from the two IP.
```

Comment: Thanks - this was broken in 14.10 / Trusty also. Creating the file and restarting the service works.