# Telnet after update to 15.04 not working

Tags: networking, server, 15.04, telnet

I updated to 15.04 using the server command sudo do-release-upgrade.

Since the upgrade was complete and after a reboot, I am unable to telnet to the server.

Port 23 is not listened while the telnetd, xinetd are configured and restarted.

I followed instructions on
[Telnet Server not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439574/telnet-server-not-starting)
as well as on 
http://ubuntuguide.net/install-and-enable-telnet-server-in-ubuntu-linux

restarted a few times but telnet is just not there.  Connections are refused.

The server has not changed its IP address and it is the same network as before.  There are no firewalls blocking access.

I also installed it from fresh (on a VM) and neither telnet or ssh work.  Connection refused on ports 22 and 23.

Any recommendations?

Further to comments below,
telnet and ssh do not work from the server itself let alone from PCs on the same network.  Before the upgrade the telnet & ssh was operating and after the upgrade, a couple of hours later, it did not.  I used a telnet session to login and kick start the upgrade.  It is definitely not a firewall issue.

I used the latest ISO image for the VM and the automatic update from the server.

Comment: Don't use `telnet`: all data, including your password, is sent in the clear.  Use `ssh` instead.

Comment: ssh is not working either.  Connection is refused on port 22 as well.

Comment: Then you've got a firewall somewhere, like in the vm.

Comment: A comment on the referenced question begain "It is 2014".  It is now 2015, and you have Ubuntu version 15.  You should be [edit]ing your question to show people, for example, what `systemctl status sshd.socket` tells you.

Comment: The version 15.04 is the latest as found on:15.04 is the latest to date: http://releases.ubuntu.com/vivid/.  The systemctl status sshd.socket returns: "Loaded: not-found (Reason no such file or directory), Active: inactive (dead).  Very strange for an out-of-the-box latest install.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any one has any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I never managed to have it working but instead I discovered that SSH works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems, but after installing the packages `xinetd` and `telnetd` it's working fine.

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd.
```